Comparisons in german
When making comparisons with "als" in German, do you need a comma?
For example:

Der Autor sagt, dass Doping häufiger ist als wir gedacht haben.


Der Autor sagt, dass Doping häufiger ist, als wir gedacht haben.

In the case that we don't use a comma, is it normal that we have 2 verbs in the sentence (ist, gedacht haben)?

In German "als" is used as a conjunction (connector of sentences).
If a comparing conjunction (like "als") is followed by a subclause (nebensatz) a comma is used.
Source: Rule 5
https://www.studienkreis.de/deutsch/kommasetzung-lernen-regeln/

The relevant rule would be number 6 on the site you linked.

shouldn't you then create an answer and try to correct my mistake?

@MerlinNestler a comment is completely appropriate here to point out what might just appear to be a typo. That said, you are correct, it is indeed covered in Rule 5.

@DavidVogt: Thank you for pointing out my error
